# call function per vector element

Tags: r, element, data-conversion

I have written a simple function to calculate the average power of measurements in dBm. First I had to write the function to convert dBm to watts, find the average and the convert the value back to dBm.
This works great for a single vector

For example:

```
MeanDB <- function(dBVector) {
    # Returns the variance for all the input data. First converts data to linear scale. Then mean() is applied. 
    # Then Data are converted back to log scale
    return(10*log10(mean(10^(dBVector/10))))
}
```

Now I would like to apply the same function for elements of two vectors for example the vector1 and vector2.

I would like to call my written function for each pair of elements from vector 1 and vector 2 (these are of same size).

The easiest will be ofc a for loop

```
keepResults<-vector()
for i in seq(1,length(vector1)){
    keepResults<-MeanDb(vector1[i],vector2[i])
}
```

but I am quite sure there should be in R a more efficient alternatives. Can you provide commands in R that can do that in a shorter way?
Regards and thanks
Alex

Comment: Probably with `mapply` you could do `mapply(function(x, y) MeanDB(c(x, y)), vector1, vector2)`.

Comment: This answer actually looks better than my suggestion, since you don't have to rewrite your specified function. I'd go with this one.

Comment: To generalize to many vectors, you can use `...` like this `mapply(function(...) MeanDB(c(...)), vector1, vector2, vector3)` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for `*apply` loops. Simply write a vectorized function:

```
MeanDB <- function(...) {
  stopifnot(length(unique(lengths(list(...)))) == 1L)
  M <- cbind(...)
  return(10 * log10(rowMeans(10 ^ (M / 10))))
}

a = c(1, 2, 3)
b = c(2, 3, 4)
MeanDB(a, b)
```

This generalizes to an arbitrary number of vectors.

Comment: looks interesting reply. What the input of the function can be then? And I guess this should be by element averaging. Right?

Comment: The input can be numeric vectors of equal length. It does the same as the other answers which is what I understand to be your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For just two lists, you could rewrite your function as:

```
MeanDB <- function(number1,number2) {
  return(10*log10(mean(10^(c(number1,number2)/10))))
}

# Example of implementation:
a = list(1,2,3)
b = list(2,3,4)
mapply(MeanDB,a,b)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pmap` (general case) or `map2` (in this case) from the `purrr` package. If I used the function defined by @F.Maas above then,

```
MeanDB <- function(number1,number2) {
return(10*log10(mean(10^(c(number1,number2)/10))))
}
pmap_dbl(list(list(1,2,3),list(4,5,6)),MeanDB)
```